# Binary Bomb Defusal Calling Function

Tags: c, assembly, binary-bomb

So I've been working on this binary bomb for days and I am nearly finished. Just two more phases to go, and it is due tomorrow night. I've worked through the disassembled code as posted below and I can't seem to figure out exactly what is happening.

What I do know is that the fscanf function is called and requests two inputs "%d %d" given by the string $0x8048baa. We'll call these inputs y and x in that order. After entering two inputs, the program will continue without exploding and see whether y is less than 4. Next, a comparison is done to see if y is positive, and if not, then it is changed to a positive and restored into %eax.

Next, the function f is called (disassembled code below) with y as a parameter. I am slightly confused on line <+4> of this function, as 0x20(%esp) lies outside of the space allocated for this function and into the previously stored items. 0x20(%esp) seems to refer to the pointer to y which was pushed to the stack earlier. I'm not sure if this is right, as I don't understand why the program would reference a pointer to y which was previously stored outside of the call to this method when y is already stored in the stack as an argument to the current function. Anyway, I don't know what else would be happening here so if that *is* what is happening, then y is stored into %ebx then if y is less than 1 the program jumps forward, otherwise a new address is loaded into eax and then the function is recursively called? I don't fully understand what happens here so I am just hoping that I can get by without having to go through the recursive call by setting y to something less than 1 initially. If y is less than 1 then the eax register is set to 1, y becomes 1, and then we return back to phase_4_of_5.

Now y is added to itself. After exiting the f function, y == 1 so y + y = 2. Next a comparison is done to see whether y and x are equal, and if they are then we skip to a second comparison making sure that x does not equal the value 240. If x != 240 then the program resets the stack pointer and returns.

By my (obviously flawed) logic, if y were initially -5 and x were initially 2, then I should make it through without blowing up the bomb.

Perhaps someone could point me in the right direction here? I am not sure exactly where I am going wrong and am having a hard time fully understand the f function. It is important to me that I actually understand my assignments, so if you would like to supply me with a working input so that I can walk through the program step by step with it, do so knowing that I am still learning.

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_4_of_5:
   0x08048890 <+0>:     sub    $0x2c,%esp            ;allocate 44 bytes for stack
   0x08048893 <+3>:     lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax       ;load address of x into eax
   0x08048897 <+7>:     mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)        ;prepare &x for function call
   0x0804889b <+11>:    lea    0x18(%esp),%eax       ;load address of y into eax
   0x0804889f <+15>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)        ;prepare &y for function call
   0x080488a3 <+19>:    movl   $0x8048baa,0x4(%esp)  ;prepare "%d %d" for call
   0x080488ab <+27>:    mov    0x804b040,%eax        ;load call to fscanf into eax
   0x080488b0 <+32>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)           ;push call to fscanf onto stack
   0x080488b3 <+35>:    call   0x8048480 <__isoc99_fscanf@plt>  ;call fscanf("%d %d", &y, &x);
   0x080488b8 <+40>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax             ;if((# of numbers entered == 2))
   0x080488bb <+43>:    je     0x80488c9 <phase_4_of_5+57>  ;jump to <+57>
   0x080488bd <+45>:    movl   $0x4,(%esp)
   0x080488c4 <+52>:    call   0x80486ef <explode>
   0x080488c9 <+57>:    mov    0x18(%esp),%eax       ;move y into eax
   0x080488cd <+61>:    cmp    $0x4,%eax             ;if(y <= 4)
   0x080488d0 <+64>:    jle    0x80488de <phase_4_of_5+78>  ;jump to <+78>
   0x080488d2 <+66>:    movl   $0x4,(%esp)
   0x080488d9 <+73>:    call   0x80486ef <explode>
   0x080488de <+78>:    test   %eax,%eax             ;if(y >= 0) 
   0x080488e0 <+80>:    jns    0x80488e8 <phase_4_of_5+88>  ;jump to <+88>
   0x080488e2 <+82>:    neg    %eax                  ;else y = -y;
   0x080488e4 <+84>:    mov    %eax,0x18(%esp)       ;update y
   0x080488e8 <+88>:    mov    0x18(%esp),%eax       ;update eax (unnecessary?)
   0x080488ec <+92>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)           ;load y as argument to f
   0x080488ef <+95>:    call   0x8048869 <f>         ;call f
   0x080488f4 <+100>:   add    %eax,%eax
   0x080488f6 <+102>:   mov    0x1c(%esp),%edx
   0x080488fa <+106>:   cmp    %eax,%edx
   0x080488fc <+108>:   je     0x804890a <phase_4_of_5+122>
   0x080488fe <+110>:   movl   $0x4,(%esp)
   0x08048905 <+117>:   call   0x80486ef <explode>
   0x0804890a <+122>:   cmp    $0xf0,%edx
   0x08048910 <+128>:   jne    0x804891e <phase_4_of_5+142>
   0x08048912 <+130>:   movl   $0x8048c98,(%esp)
   0x08048919 <+137>:   call   0x80484d0 <puts@plt>
   0x0804891e <+142>:   add    $0x2c,%esp
   0x08048921 <+145>:   ret
End of assembler dump.


Dump of assembler code for function f:
   0x08048869 <+0>:     push   %ebx                ;load new base pointer
   0x0804886a <+1>:     sub    $0x18,%esp          ;make more room on the stack
   0x0804886d <+4>:     mov    0x20(%esp),%ebx     ;move arg(y) into ebx
   0x08048871 <+8>:     cmp    $0x1,%ebx           ;if(y <= 1)
   0x08048874 <+11>:    jle    0x8048886 <f+29>    ;jump to <+29>
   0x08048876 <+13>:    lea    -0x1(%ebx),%eax     ;else ??? what is happening here? 1 byte below ebx? does this mean I am dealing with low order and high order areas on the stack?
   0x08048879 <+16>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0804887c <+19>:    call   0x8048869 <f>       ;recursively call f until ebx <= 1
   0x08048881 <+24>:    imul   %ebx,%eax           ;eax = eax*ebx
   0x08048884 <+27>:    jmp    0x804888b <f+34>    ;jump to <+34>
   0x08048886 <+29>:    mov    $0x1,%eax           ;Does this literally mean to store the value '1' into eax? If so, what was the point of imul?
   0x0804888b <+34>:    add    $0x18,%esp          ;return esp to loc before call to f.
   0x0804888e <+37>:    pop    %ebx
   0x0804888f <+38>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: `0x20(%esp)` is the regular calling-convention position for `f`'s arg, after it modified `%esp` by pushing `%ebx` and doing `sub $0x18, %esp`.  If you want anyone to help you further, comment the disassembly listing with what you've figured out so far.  I mostly just skimmed your question, but I didn't see anything about a buffer overflow attack against the bomb.

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad. I just changed the title. I had originally started writing a question about the previous phase which did involve buffer overflow but I solved it as I was typing out the question. Now I'm stumped on the next phase. I'll comment the listing.

Comment: The first part of my comment was addressing your 3rd paragraph, where you're confused about how `f` is getting is arg.  You know that `call` pushes a return address, right?  So on entry, `(%esp)` points at that, and `0x4(%esp)` points at the first arg.  `f` modifies `%esp` *before* it loads its arg from the stack, so it's not actually doing anything weird like accessing other data from its caller.  You know that the 32bit ABI passes args on the stack, right?  See [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I actually was forgetting about the return value. I still don't see how f is accessing the first argument though, as after the instruction at <+1> is ran, esp is located at -0x18 (24) relative to ebp and in <+4> we are trying to load a value located at 0x20 (32) relative to esp, which is 0x8 (8) relative to ebp, which is one higher than it should be. Am I forgetting to push something else to the stack? Does the call to f itself get pushed onto the stack followed by the return address?

Comment: Scratch that, I forgot to push new ebp onto the stack. Excuse me for being such a rookie to this. Our professor just threw assembly onto us and I didn't even know c until 2 weeks ago. Now I am confused about what is happening at <f+13> and onward.

Comment: Note that `f()` pushes `%ebX`, not `%ebP`.  It was compiled with the default setting of `-fomit-frame-pointer`, so it's not making a stack frame (which would also involve `mov %esp, %ebp` before the `sub` that reserves some space for locals).  Learning C and assembly at the same time is not a bad way to go about it, actually.  Everything in C maps fairly directly to asm, other than `switch` statements.  Compilers are really clever at optimizing them into branch trees, or lookup tables, or bitmap checks...

Comment: Also, terminology: `esp` is *offset by* -0x18 relative to `ebp`.  `esp`'s value is always *located* in `esp`. :P  Located relative to a register kinda sounds like in memory at some offset from a pointer.  Also, `call` pushes a "return address".  The *return value* is in `eax` when the function returns.  And I have no idea what you mean by "does the call to f itself get pushed onto the stack"?  The `call` instruction is simple: push EIP, then jump.  A function, or a function-call, isn't something you can push onto the stack. (C and asm don't have closures, other than function-pointers... nvm)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I did find an answer. I finally figured out that the f function is simply performing a factorial on the argument entered and returning that value into eax. Where y and x are two inputs, x must equal (y!)*2, so my working input was y = 4, x = 48.